# Sort by id element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<li id="pi_div2"></li>
<li id="pi_div5"></li>
<li id="pi_div4"></li>
```

I need to sort like this:

```
<li id="pi_div2"></li>
<li id="pi_div4"></li>
<li id="pi_div5"></li>
```

My script now:

```
<script>
    $("li[id*=pi_div]").sort(function(a,b) {
        if(a.id < b.id) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }).each(function() { console.log($(this).attr("id"));});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Comment: Use numbers as first charachter in `id` or classnames is inavlid.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Based upon your original html, you could do something like this:

**Html:**

```
<ul id="cat">
    <li id="3">Text 3</li>
    <li id="1">Text 1</li>
    <li id="2">Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#cat li").sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.id) > parseInt(b.id);
}).each(function () {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.remove();
    $(elem).appendTo("#cat");
});
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THMu3/).

---

**EDIT:**

As @KiKo has correctly pointed out, the above code breaks if you have a list longer than ten elements. You can fix this by replacing the "greater than" in the sort function with a minus.

**Html:**

```
<ul id="cat">
  <li id="3">Text 3</li>
  <li id="2">Text 2</li>
  <li id="1">Text 1</li>
  <li id="9">Text 9</li>
  <li id="11">Text 11</li>
  <li id="5">Text 5</li>
  <li id="7">Text 7</li>
  <li id="6">Text 6</li>
  <li id="12">Text 12</li>
  <li id="4">Text 4</li>
  <li id="10">Text 10</li>
  <li id="8">Text 8</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#cat li").sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseInt(a.id) - parseInt(b.id);
}).each(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  elem.remove();
  $(elem).appendTo("#cat");
});
```

[Here's a new JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/THMu3/370/)

Comment: That solution is the only one that can process dozens of timestamp-like numbers!

Comment: Both solution still working!

Comment: Briliant! Thank you!

Comment: The only issue I've found with this method is that is does not work if the first element has a lower number than the 2nd. If the first element has an ID of 1, followed by 3, 2, 4, for example, the 3 will be ignored and the list will appear as 3,1,2,4.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kq9nF/1/) is a solution.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="initial">
    <ul id="cat">
        <li id="3">Text 3</li>
        <li id="1">Text 1</li>
        <li id="2">Text 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="new"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

First, find out how many list items there are.  Then go through each one, in order, and add it to a string that you eventually print out on screen.

```
var size = $('#cat > li').size()

var string = '<ul>';

for(var i = 1; i<=size; i++){
    string = string.concat('<li>' + $('#'+i+'').html() + '</li>');
}

string = string.concat('</ul>');

$('.new').html(string);
```

Comment: The last line could also be `$('.initial').html(string);` and would just replace the first list with the new one.  Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kq9nF/2/).

Comment: this is quick and cool