# Change div order based on their id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have disorder div in HTML page and that need to in ascending order based on their id.
I have some code but it is not working I just want to know what is wrong with code or do i need to do some more work with code. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/en107qxb/)

**Jquery**

```
$('div').sort(function (a, b) {
var contentA =parseInt( $(a).attr('data-sort'));
var contentB =parseInt( $(b).attr('data-sort'));      
return (contentA < contentB) ? -1 : (contentA > contentB) ? 1 : 0;
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-sort='14'>14</div>
<div data-sort='6'>6</div>
<div data-sort='9'>9</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267120/jquery-sort-by-id-element

This helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
var asc=false;   
var sorted=$('div').sort(function(a,b){
    return (asc ==
           ($(a).data('sort') <  $(b).data('sort'))) ? 1 : -1;
});
asc = asc ? false : true;
$('body').html(sorted);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/avgom8aw/)**

Answer (score 1):

Given that your data is integer based and the sort you need is ascending order, there is a neat way to do this with pure css  :)

Just put your data divs inside a parent flexbox container and make your sort integer a css order property, like so...

```
<div id="container" style="display:flex">
    <div style="order:14">14</div>
    <div style="order:6">6</div>
    <div style="order:9">9</div>
</div>
```

Only works in 'modern' browsers though.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/en107qxb/5/

```
    function sortUsingText(parent, childSelector) {
    var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
        var vA = $(a).text();
        var vB = $(b).text();
        return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    parent.append(items);
}


  sortUsingText($('#sortThis'), "div");



function sortUsingData(parent, childSelector) {
    var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
        var vA = $(a).data('sort');
        var vB = $(b).data('sort');
        return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    parent.append(items);
}
  sortUsingData($('#sortThisData'), "div");
```

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="sortThis">
    <div>3</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
</div>

<div id="sortThisData">
    <div data-sort="7">High</div>
    <div data-sort="2">Low</div>
    <div data-sort="5">Mid</div>
</div>
```