# How to re-Order html child elements in Dom based on id value

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a parent div with some child elements. I want to re-order child elements based on two id values. for example 1,4. It means to grab the item with id 1 and insert it above the item with id 4.

```
    <div class="parent">
        <div id="1">First</div>
        <div id="2">Second</div>
        <div id="3">Third</div>
        <div id="4">Fourth</div>
        <div id="5">Fifth</div>
    </div>
```

Making a drag and drop component for react.  And this is what i have tried

```
    const element = document.getElementById('1') //dragStart
    const targetElement = document.getElementById('4') //dragEnter

    const parent = document.querySelector('.parent') // drop
    parent.insertBefore(element, targetElement)
```

But problem is when i grab the first element and want to put it on the bottom (last child). It fails to do so. How to put a child element after last child with insertBefore() method?

Comment: *"Tried with parent.insertBefore(). But not getting the desired result."* Show us that attempt so we can help you understand where it went wrong. That's exactly the right method to use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267120/sort-by-id-element-using-jquery This might help you

Comment: Provided these elements are in the **first** element with `class="parent"`, your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/yfwob2hs/ So I'm guessing they aren't in the first element with that class. But in any case, you don't want to get the parent separately. If you want to put the element in front of the target, use the target's `parentNode` as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how you are using [**`insertBefore()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) but there should not be any issues:

**Update:** The issue could be that your code is running before the DOM is fully loaded. You can wrap your code with [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event):

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const element = document.getElementById('1') //dragStart
  const targetElement = document.getElementById('4') //dragEnter

  const parent = document.querySelector('.parent') // drop
  parent.insertBefore(element, targetElement)
});

</script>

<div class="parent">
  <div id="1">First</div>
  <div id="2">Second</div>
  <div id="3">Third</div>
  <div id="4">Fourth</div>
  <div id="5">Fifth</div>
</div>
```

Placing the first element as the last element using [**`nextSibling`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling):

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const parentNode = document.querySelector('.parent');
  const element = document.getElementById('1') //dragStart
  const targetElement = document.querySelector('.parent').lastElementChild //get last child
  parentNode.insertBefore(element, targetElement.nextSibling);
});

</script>

<div class="parent">
  <div id="1">First</div>
  <div id="2">Second</div>
  <div id="3">Third</div>
  <div id="4">Fourth</div>
  <div id="5">Fifth</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check my question again to see the problem with this method

Comment: @FishLegs, you have a typo in `document.querrySelector('.parent')`.... should be `query` not `querry`...

Comment: @FishLegs, it seems your code is running before the DOM is fully loaded. Please check the update where I have used exact your code with `DOMContentLoaded`:)

Comment: i solved the problem by attaching the nextElementSibling on targetElement

Comment: @FishLegs, that's great, but the answer here shows that your code is working as expected with `DOMContentLoaded`:)

Comment: @FishLegs, added another answer, please check:)

Comment: i want to use splice method instead of insertBefore.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This answers [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60474666/1). The question has now been edited to reference React. You wouldn't use the following in a React project. You'd reorder the state that the DOM represents, and then let React handle updating the DOM.

---

You're right to use `insertBefore`:

```
function moveElement(move, before) {
    // Get the element to move
    const elToMove = document.getElementById(move);
    // Get the element to put it in front of
    const elBefore = document.getElementById(before);
    // Move it
    elBefore.parentNode.insertBefore(elToMove, elBefore);
}
```

```js
function moveElement(move, before) {
    const elToMove = document.getElementById(move);
    const elBefore = document.getElementById(before);
    elBefore.parentNode.insertBefore(elToMove, elBefore);
}

setTimeout(() => {
    moveElement("1", "4");
}, 800);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div id="1">First</div>
    <div id="2">Second</div>
    <div id="3">Third</div>
    <div id="4">Fourth</div>
    <div id="5">Fifth</div>
</div>
```

---

Side note: I suggest avoiding having `id` values that start with digits. Although they're perfectly valid HTML and they work just fine with `getElementById`, they're a pain if you need to target them with CSS, because a CSS ID selector (`#example`) can't start with an unescaped digit. For instance, `document.querySelector("#1")` fails. You have to escape the `1` with a hex sequence, which isn't terrifically clear: `document.querySelector("#\\31")` (the characters `\`, `3`, and `1`: `0x31` = `49` = the Unicode code point for `1`).

Comment: I have updated my question with the problem i am getting this way. Your css advice is helpful

Comment: @FishLegs - See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474666/how-to-re-order-html-child-elements-in-dom-based-on-id-value/60474705?noredirect=1#comment106984385_60474666) on the question.

Comment: can't we use splice method instead of insertBefore?

Comment: @FishLegs - What `splice` method? There aren't any arrays or strings involved here, which are the two things that have `splice` that I'm aware of. Also...why would you want to? `insertBefore` is exactly the right tool for this.

Comment: i think in react its not allowed to interact with dom directly. So i want to use ref's, nodelists converted to array and splice. React Framework doesn't like simple things like insertBefore or querySelector

Comment: @FishLegs - The [version of the question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60474666/1) said nothing about React. Questions are not supposed to be moving targets. And yes indeed, you shouldn't be directly manipulating the DOM in React. Instead, reorder the state that the DOM represents, and let React reorder the DOM. But you wouldn't do that with `splice`, because `splice` modifies the original array and you never directly modify state in React. Instead, create a *new* array in the updated order.